# mdadm and RAID-5 recovery

Tags: data-recovery, raid, raid5

I am encountering some problems with my RAID-5 array, using mdadm and Debian.

First of all, I lost a drive (completely, it is not even recognized by the BIOS), then I replaced it with a new one; rebuilding has started but has been interrupted by a read error on the second disk (and this one has been removed):

```
raid5:md0: read error not correctable (sector 1398118536 on sdd)
```

I suppose that this one will die in the next few days, but I want to re-add it to work with a degraded array to perform some backups (only few sectors are broken and I hope to save a maximum of data before it fails).

Here are my disks, in the RAID order:

1. **sdc** - OK
2. **sdd** - (the one with read errors, removed from array while rebuilding)
3. **sde** - (the one that died, replaced by a spare, but obviously interrupted while rebuilding => I'm not convinced about its data integrity)
4. **sdf** - OK

The fact is that I can't re-add **sdd** to the array, using this command:

```
# mdadm --assemble /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdd1 /dev/sdf1 --force --run
mdadm: failed to RUN_ARRAY /dev/md0: Input/output error
mdadm: Not enough devices to start the array.
# mdadm -D /dev/md0 
/dev/md0:
        Version : 0.90
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 24 14:20:39 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465039488 (1397.17 GiB 1500.20 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0
    Persistence : Superblock is persistent

    Update Time : Sun Oct 23 01:57:22 2011
          State : active, FAILED, Not Started
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 0
  Spare Devices : 1

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

           UUID : 01017848:84926c43:1751c931:a76e1cde (local to host tryphon)
         Events : 0.131544

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
       1       0        0        1      removed
       2       0        0        2      removed
       3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1

       4       8       49        -      spare   /dev/sdd1
```

As you can see, sdd is recognized as a spare instead of being in sync as RAID device #1.

And I have no idea how to tell mdadm that sdd is RAID device #1.

If anyone has any idea, it would be so great!

Thanks.

---

PS: if this helps, here is the output of mdadm disk examination:

```
# mdadm -E /dev/sd[cdef]1
/dev/sdc1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 01017848:84926c43:1751c931:a76e1cde (local to host tryphon)
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 24 14:20:39 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465039488 (1397.17 GiB 1500.20 GB)
     Array Size : 4395118464 (4191.51 GiB 4500.60 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Oct 23 01:57:22 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
     Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : dfeeeace - correct
         Events : 131544

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8       49        4      spare   /dev/sdd1
/dev/sdd1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 01017848:84926c43:1751c931:a76e1cde (local to host tryphon)
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 24 14:20:39 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465039488 (1397.17 GiB 1500.20 GB)
     Array Size : 4395118464 (4191.51 GiB 4500.60 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Oct 23 01:57:22 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : dfeeeae0 - correct
         Events : 131544

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     4       8       49        4      spare   /dev/sdd1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8       49        4      spare   /dev/sdd1
/dev/sde1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 01017848:84926c43:1751c931:a76e1cde (local to host tryphon)
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 24 14:20:39 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465039488 (1397.17 GiB 1500.20 GB)
     Array Size : 4395118464 (4191.51 GiB 4500.60 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 4
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sat Oct 22 22:11:52 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : dfeeb657 - correct
         Events : 131534

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     4       8       65        4      spare   /dev/sde1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
   2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8       65        4      spare   /dev/sde1
/dev/sdf1:
          Magic : a92b4efc
        Version : 0.90.00
           UUID : 01017848:84926c43:1751c931:a76e1cde (local to host tryphon)
  Creation Time : Tue Aug 24 14:20:39 2010
     Raid Level : raid5
  Used Dev Size : 1465039488 (1397.17 GiB 1500.20 GB)
     Array Size : 4395118464 (4191.51 GiB 4500.60 GB)
   Raid Devices : 4
  Total Devices : 3
Preferred Minor : 0

    Update Time : Sun Oct 23 01:57:22 2011
          State : clean
 Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
 Failed Devices : 2
  Spare Devices : 1
       Checksum : dfeeeb04 - correct
         Events : 131544

         Layout : left-symmetric
     Chunk Size : 128K

      Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
this     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1

   0     0       8       33        0      active sync   /dev/sdc1
   1     1       0        0        1      faulty removed
       2     2       0        0        2      faulty removed
   3     3       8       81        3      active sync   /dev/sdf1
   4     4       8       49        4      spare   /dev/sdd1
```

Answer (score 1):

**What you need first is off-RAID copy of sdD**. Use `dd_rescue`, for e. g.. Don't use this disk in that RAID while recovering it.

When you have this copy, use it to **start the array w/o** sdE — put instead of it keyword `missing`. Two hints how this can be done, even if direct way with `--force` fails:

1) You can re-create your RAID with `--assume-clean`. (Don't forget this option since with it only superblocks will be updated, not parity).

2) You can `-A` assemble array.

**In both cases you have to provide absolutley the same config options** (layout, chunk size, disk order, …) as your broken RAID has. In fact I'd recommend starting with -A-ssembling, since it even doesn't update superblock, while letting you access your data. Only when you're sure it's properly assembling, you can make it persistent with assume-clean re-creation.

As soon as you would have running RAID with 3 disks, just put your sdE instead of missing one.